# How to create new Virtual Desktops in a script to launch multiple applications in multiple desktops in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

In the case where hibernation is not possible, after turn off and turn on the computer would be useful have a script to reconfigure the system as it was before:

How to write a script to launch multiple applications in multiple desktops in Windows 10 ?

To do this the key is to create Virtual Desktops in the script.

It Would be preferably to do that using commands from the PowerShell.

**Update**

A general look in the procedure:

To use the PowerShell IDE, as it allows to write the script and to run commands and scrits in the same environment.

Procedure to create the script:

1. To insert the path and file of the executable (taked from shortcuts);
2. To insert delay
3. To create a new Virtual Desktop (preferably using PowerShell commands);
4. To insert delay
5. Repeat

Procedure to run the script:

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
2. To run the script
3. Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted

How to create Virtual Desktops using PowerShell commands ?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33271721) on the very same question was voted useful. Give it a try.

Comment: The a idea (described by @Shaun Webb) is to open apps running a script with the sequence of apps calls plus a line to do a delay and a call to create the Virtual Desktop, for exemple: calc Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 [CSharpPS.PS]::NewVD() Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 notepad. For create a Virtual Desktops they used a script based in the Input Simulator project (inputsimulator.codeplex.com). I not yet tried the script.

Answer (score 3):

WIN + CTRL + D: Create a new desktop

```
$KeyShortcut = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
//WIN + CTRL + D: Create a new desktop
public static void CreateVirtualDesktopInWin10()
{
    //Key down
    keybd_event((byte)0x5B, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //Left Windows key 
    keybd_event((byte)0x11, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //CTRL
    keybd_event((byte)0x44, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //D
    //Key up
    keybd_event((byte)0x5B, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
    keybd_event((byte)0x11, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
    keybd_event((byte)0x44, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
}
"@ -Name CreateVirtualDesktop -UsingNamespace System.Threading -PassThru
   $KeyShortcut::CreateVirtualDesktopInWin10()
```

More details [How to create new Virtual Desktop in Windows 10 using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-create-new-Virtual-0e972c8d)